# Compare data in database with jquery and json

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, jquery, json

Is it returning me error 500 syntax, does anyone see any errors?

**jQuery Code**

```
            var ordertxt = $j("#ordertxt"); 
                ordertxt.blur(function() { 
                    $j.ajax({ 
                        url: '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('contato/index/verifica') ?>', 
                        type: 'POST', 
                        data:{"ordertxt" : ordertxt.val()}, 
                        success: function(data) { 
                        console.log(data); 
                        data = $j.parseJSON(data); 
                        $j("#msg_pedido").text(data.ordertxt);
                    } 
                }); 
            });
```

**Controller Action**

```
    public function verificaAction() {

            if(isset($_POST['ordertxt'])){ 

            //Recebe o Email Postado
            $ordertxt = $_POST['ordertxt'];

            //Conecta banco de dados 
            $sql = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($ordertxt) or print mysql_error();

            //Se o retorno for maior do que zero, diz que já existe um.
            if ($sql[0]['increment_id'] == $ordertxt) {
                echo json_encode(array('ordertxt' => 'Pedido Valido')); 
            }else{ 
                echo json_encode(array('ordertxt' => 'Pedido Invalido.' )); 
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: do you get `$ordertxt` in your controller?

Comment: Yes, by getPost

Comment: do you get increment id `$ordertexto[0]['increment_id']` here?

Comment: Yes, I look at the table by Mage :: getModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

**jQuery**

```
            var ordertxt = $j("#ordertxt"); 
                ordertxt.blur(function() { 
                    $j.ajax({ 
                        url: '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('contato/index/verifica') ?>', 
                        type: 'POST', 
                        data:{"ordertxt" : ordertxt.val()}, 
                        success: function(data) { 
                        console.log(data); 
                        data = $j.parseJSON(data); 
                        $j("#msg_pedido").text(data.ordertxt);
                    } 
                }); 
            });
```

**Action**

```
    public function verificaAction() {

                if(isset($_POST['ordertxt'])){ 

                $ordertxt = $_POST['ordertxt'];


                $sql = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($ordertxt);


                if($sql->getIncrementId()){
                    echo json_encode(array('ordertxt' => 'Pedido valido')); 
                }
                else  {
                    echo json_encode(array('ordertxt' => 'Pedido Inválido.' )); 
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading all the orders and then filter one. Load Particular one

```
 $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($ordertxt);
```

Comment: I edited the question because I edited my code with what you gave me, I believe it is an error in the comparison logic or in the sql connection, It returns me, but even if the request is valid it only returns the else

Comment: If it has no value, it's valid request, if it has any value it invalid.

Comment: what will you get `$sql[0]['increment_id']` in this variable?

Comment: here $sql = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($ordertxt) or print mysql_error();

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you get an apache 500 error when you are saying "Is it returning me error 500 syntax"? If so this is an apache internal server error. Check your websevers logs first to get a clue what is going wrong.

This will give you a good clue on where to look before diving deep into your code. **Solve the 500 internal server  error first and then dive back into your code.**